# Is Tkatchenko's MBD-NL method self-consistent?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, orbitals, intermolecular-forces, density-functional-theory

I have a question regarding Tkatchenko's [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.03073)] new nonlocal many-body dispersion method (MBD-NL). Does anyone know if it's a self-consistent method? I read this paper many times but I'm still not sure.

#### References

1. Hermann, J.; Tkatchenko, A. Density-Functional Model for van Der Waals Interactions: Unifying Atomic Approaches with Nonlocal Functionals. [arXiv:1910.03073](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.03073) [cond-mat, physics:physics] **2019**.

Comment: This question might get more attention on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/)